# Wordpress: Getting Posts From A Category Using Category Name/Slug

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to display Wordpress posts from a particular category, on a non Wordpress part of my site, retrieving posts by category name/slug.

Please note, I cannot use category ID, because I am dynamically matching the slug using a category structure on the non WP part of the site.

The following works, but it seems to retrieve posts from ANY category, rather than just the united-states category.  Where am I going wrong.

```
 <div class="row">
            <div class="small-12 columns">
                <div class="row small-up-1 medium-up-3 large-up-3">
                    <?php
                    require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/blog/wp-load.php');
                    $args = array(
                        'category_name' => united-states,
                        'posts_per_page' => 3
                    );
                    $latest_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
                    if ( $latest_posts->have_posts() ) {
                        while ( $latest_posts->have_posts() ) {
                            $latest_posts->the_post(); ?>

                            <?php
                            $urli = get_permalink();
                            $remove = 'http://urlremoved.com/' ;
                            $trimmed = str_replace($remove, '', $urli) ;
                            ?>
                            <div class="column"><div class="hpPost">
                                    <div class="image cover">
                                        <a href="<?php echo $trimmed; ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(medium); ?></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="title">
                                        <a href="<?php echo $trimmed; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="desc"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>

                                </div></div>
                        <?php }
                    } else {
                        echo '<p>There are no posts available</p>';
                    }
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: put quotes around 'united-states'

Comment: Thanks... I have made that change and now it produces no results. Yet there are posts in that category.

Comment: In like blank divs or 'there are no posts available'?

Comment: There are no posts available

Comment: try it without `'posts_per_page' => 3`

Comment: Sadly that does not work either

Comment: I have it working now... it was a WP problem and not the code... I'm sorry to waste your time.

Comment: No problem, glad you solved it :-)

Comment: Having said that, your comment about adding quotes helped a lot, so thanks very much.

Comment: you're welcome :)